# Databinding with Winforms and EF 4.1 Code first

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm trying to get a Winforms combobox to automatically refresh when new rows are written to our database.

POCO EF class:

```
public class BaseSweep 
{
    public int BaseSweepId { get; set; }
    //stuff removed for clarity
}
```

I'm binding to the data through a BindingList like this:

```
public BindingList<BaseSweep> TopSweeps()
{
    LocalDbContext.BaseSweep.Load();
    return LocalDbContext.BaseSweep.Local.ToBindingList();                     

}

private void BindSweepList() //called in Form_Load
{
    comboBoxSweepIds.DataSource = _dataAccess.TopSweeps();
    comboBoxSweepIds.DisplayMember = "BaseSweepId";
    comboBoxSweepIds.ValueMember = "BaseSweepId";
}
```

This works fine for the initial binding, shows the current Ids in the table. As new rows are added to the table, the count in `LocalDbContext.BaseSweep.Local` goes up as expected. However, `comboBoxSweepIds` never updates. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark W led me the right way:

```
//put an event handler on the collection
public void CollectionChanged<T>(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler eventHandler) where T : class
{
     LocalDbContext.Set<T>().Local.CollectionChanged += eventHandler;
}
```

Use a private `BindingList<T>` in the form class (`_sweepCollection`)

On the first databind, set up the event handler:

```
private void BindSweepList()
{            
    _sweepCollection = _dataAccess.TopSweeps();
    _dataAccess.CollectionChanged<CableSweepDebug>(new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Local_CollectionChanged));

    UpdateSweepsData();
}

private void Local_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     UpdateSweepsData();
}

private void UpdateSweepsData()
{
    if (comboBoxSweepIds.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new UpdateSweepCount(UpdateSweepsData));
    }
    else
    {
        var tmpBind = _sweepCollection.OrderByDescending(t => t.BaseSweepId).Take(100);

        comboBoxSweepIds.DataSource = null;
        comboBoxSweepIds.DataSource = tmpBind.ToList() ;
        comboBoxSweepIds.DisplayMember = "BaseSweepId";
        comboBoxSweepIds.ValueMember = "BaseSweepId";                

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire an event and call bind each time a row is added.